# Why is my onClick function adding two entries to mySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs

I've been learning how to use a React.js front end combined with a PHP server backend and making a simple project that has to do with adding, editing, and displaying recipes in a recipe-book database. My AddRecipe.js almost works, but there's one big problem where everytime I click the "Add Recipe" button, it adds two entries into my database: one empty and one with all parameters correctly inside. I've debugged the code and realized that 'handleSubmit' is only being called once: [debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Firf.png). I've tried everything that I know but I don't know what my problem is. This is what is added when I press my "Add Recipe" button:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TmAH.png) Here is my code

```
//AddRecipe.js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const AddRecipe = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState('');
  const [instructions, setInstructions] = useState('');
  const isSubmittingRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Rendering AddRecipe component');
  }, []);

  const addRecipe = () => {
    isSubmittingRef.current = true;
    console.log('Data to be sent:', { title, ingredients, instructions });
    axios
      .post('http://localhost/add_recipe.php', {
        title,
        ingredients,
        instructions,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Successful response:', response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        isSubmittingRef.current = false;
      });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!isSubmittingRef.current) {
      addRecipe();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Add Recipe</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Title:</label>
        <input type="text" value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />

        <label>Ingredients:</label>
        <textarea value={ingredients} onChange={(e) => setIngredients(e.target.value)}></textarea>

        <label>Instructions:</label>
        <textarea value={instructions} onChange={(e) => setInstructions(e.target.value)}></textarea>

        <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmittingRef.current}>
          Add Recipe
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddRecipe;
```

```
#add_recipe.php
<?php
include 'db_connection.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$title = $data->title;
$ingredients = $data->ingredients;
$instructions = $data->instructions;

$sql = "INSERT INTO recipes (title, ingredients, instructions) VALUES ('$title', '$ingredients', '$instructions')";
if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
    echo json_encode(["message" => "Recipe added successfully"]);
} else {
    echo json_encode(["error" => "Error: " . $sql, "<br>" . $conn->error]);
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

I've tried changing the button type to "submit" but the same thing happens and debugging every step, but I just don't know where the issue is.

Update: This is what I changed in add_recipe.php to fix the double insertion issue:

```
<?php
include 'db_connection.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $title = $data->title;
    $ingredients = $data->ingredients;
    $instructions = $data->instructions;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO recipes (title, ingredients, instructions) VALUES ('$title', '$ingredients', '$instructions')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
        echo json_encode(["message" => "Recipe added successfully"]);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(["error" => "Error: " . $sql, "<br>" . $conn->error]);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(["error"=> "Boohoo"]);
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Let's draw a big line down the middle of this problem.  Are you saying that `handleSubmit` gets called multiple times?  Or does your add_recipe.php do the wrong thing?  You should easily be able to test your API from postman or something and rule out your react code.  Or if the `handleSubmit` gets called twice then you can rule out your php.  I think you should do some basic debugging to narrow it down and then trim down the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that handleSubmit is only being called once. I can't tell which file is doing the wrong thing.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that handleSubmit is only being called once" - Should be pretty easy to test,  put a `window.alert('here');` in there

Comment: Consider putting a guard in add_recipe.php that guarantees that a POST happens to that page. Maybe you are getting a HEAD request, too?

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. The HEAD request was definitely the problem!!!!

Comment: @MasterGX, if you think other visitors might find that information valuable in the future (and there isn't a duplicate of it on this site already), can you post your updated working code as an answer? If you don't have time or don't think it would be helpful, it might be best to delete this. If you find a duplicate on this site, this can be closed as a duplicate which will help steer future visitors to the correct solution.